# Change all instances of a hex colour in a mysql database

Tags: mysql, database, syntax, colors

Struggling to do something that should be relatively simple. On my vBulletin board I'd like to change all instances in posts and blogs of the hex colour '#ff4080', to hex colour '#806a00'.

I've tried various REPLACE queries in phpmyadmin without effect or being able to get the syntax right. I'm happy to simply change all instances of the whole database without selecting particular tables.

Comment: A little more info is required, are the colors in specific tables and columns?

Comment: No as I said I want to change all the instances of a particular colour in all tables and all columns without exception. Don't want to limit it to particular tables/columns. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found it so far as vBulletin post text entries are concerned. This works:

UPDATE post SET pagetext = replace(pagetext, '=#FF0080', '=#ceac00');